# Enable focus follows mouse between editor and integrated terminal in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, focus

I am used to the focus follows mouse option for years.

In the VSCode editor I want to switch between the integrated terminal and the code writer by simply focusing the cursor on them.

For example in Geany editor:
[image]

Does anyone know how to enable focus follows mouse from settings or using any simple hack while trying to move between the code writer and terminal?

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is it's **not possible** at the moment.  There have been numerous issues raised in the past ([#25685](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/25685), [#44214](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/44214)) and they have been closed because "the number of votes ... and duplicate issues" are not high enough.  Go out and raise an issue and get others to vote on that issue.

There was a [pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/53963) made a couple of years ago that would introduce a `focusOnHover` setting.  This appears to resolve the issue but it has not been accepted and is now a bit stale and needs some work.  So you could for VSCode (for yourself), apply the pull request and then build it.

I am keen on this feature as well.

Answer (score 5):

It is now a candidate for the backlog, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/93772 (Provide a "focus-follow-mouse" setting)

So upvote it if you want this.  It needs 20 votes to move to the backlog.